# dock (taskbar) icon issue

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 19.10. After loading everything is running great so far. The only issue so far is the size of the dock/taskbar icons. They are so small. How do you make them bigger? I tried going to apperance-icons but nothing worked. I tried to right click the dock but there was nothing there to change to icon size. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An image such as the one provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568793/61798) would help understand what exactly you want. Please provide an image of what you have marking what you want to resize.

Comment: The image in the link that you provided are the same as the icons I want to change. The icons that are pointed at on the top right. Mine are just on the bottom right of the screen instead. In that image you see the dock bar on the left side. I have mine on the bottom as well. The icons on that bottom dock are small. IE the Firefox and kdenlive icons.

Comment: I tried the to use the advice given in the link but the message was "command not found". I am not sure what I did wrong.